# Consider all linear systems with two zero eigenvalues. Which of these systems are conjugate? Prove this.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

if a matrix $ A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}  $
has all eigenvalues $ = 0 $

then $ trace(A)=a+d=0$ i.e  $ a=-d $

and   $  det(A)=0 $ i.e $ ad = bc $

and hence $a=\pm \sqrt{-bc} $

if $ a=0 $ then $ b=c=d=0 $

if $ b=0 $(or $ c=0 $) then $ a=d=0 $

assume that $ b\neq0 $ then $ A=\begin{pmatrix}
 \sqrt{-bc} & b \\ 
c &- \sqrt{-bc}
\end{pmatrix}  $

the associated eigenvector to $0  $ is $ V_{1}=\begin{pmatrix}
b \\ 
-a
\end{pmatrix}  $

solving $ (A-0I)\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
b \\ 
-a
\end{pmatrix} $ to obtain the jordan form of $ A $ we get $ V_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
1
\end{pmatrix} $

now consider the matrix $ T=\begin{pmatrix}
b & 0 \\ 
-a & 1
\end{pmatrix}  $ and so $ T^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{1}{b} & 0 \\ 
\dfrac{a}{b} & 1
\end{pmatrix}  $

Then $ T^{-1}AT=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} =J_{A}  $
we get $ T^{-1}\varphi_{t}^{A}T=\varphi_{t}^{J_{A}} $ where $ \varphi $ is the flow map.
And all systtems are conjugated

Comment: I think you could’ve just started with the possible Jordan normal forms.

Comment: Yes , all systems are reduced to Jordan canonical form, just i gave the general case